# How to deal with a dash in an Excel VBA input variable?

Tags: string, variables, excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with an Excel VBA macro and was hoping you could give me some advice on how to fix it. In the code below, when a user clicks a command button, an InputBox pops up and the user inputs a number in the form XXX-XXXXXX (e.g. 111-222222). Then, the macro takes the value from the column adjacent to button and uses the input variable to replace a certain part of the adjacent column's value. However, when I tried to run the macro and input a number such as 123-456789, nothing happens. I believe it has something to do with the dash that the user inputs, however I'm not sure how to fix it. Please help!

```
Sub CommandButtonTitleXXXdashXXXXXX_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Worksheets("REVISIONS").Range("D3:D17").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    If n = 15 Then
        If MsgBox("Title revision box full. Add manually.", vbOKOnly, "Error") = vbOK Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Dim rs As Integer
    rs = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    Dim amount As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    amount = Application.InputBox("Enter case number:", "")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If amount = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim newCell As String
        newCell = Replace(Worksheets("TITLE").Range("A" & rs).Value, "XXX-XXXXXX", amount)
        Worksheets("REVISIONS").Range("D17").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = newCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the On Error Resume Next and see if you get any errors, as of now you may be getting an error in code but would never know because that line is ignoring them. also change the line `newCell = Replace(Worksheets("TITLE").Range("A" & rs).Value, "XXX-XXXXXX", amount)` To `Worksheets("TITLE").Range("A" & rs).Replace What:="XXX-XXXXXX", Replacement:=amount, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True` OR add `WorkSheetFunction.` Or `Application.` before the replace AS VBA Replace function and Excel Replace function are different

Comment: Good call! It apparently breaks on "If amount = False Then". I wonder if the dash makes the InputBox think it's blank?

Comment: The dash sholdn't cause it to be blank. Did you cancel out of the input box? That would return False.

Comment: Try `If amount = "" Then` instead. Any issues you have shouldn't have ANYTHING to do with any dashes.

Comment: `If amount = "" Then` works unless they press cancel because then it returns "False" and that is used as the replacement value.

Comment: `If amount = "False" Then` seems to work.

Comment: Can your Case number be like `@D1-1%#456`? If not then you have an additional problem to handle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take your code to an extra step.

No need to declare `amount` as `String`. You can keep it as a `Variant`. Also like I mentioned in the comment above

> Can your Case number be like @D1-1%#456? If not then you have an additional problem to handle ;)

See this example. I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do lemme know :) The other way would be to use REGEX to validate your Case ID. Let me know if you want that example as well.

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim amount As Variant

    '    123-$456789 <~~ Invalid
    '    123-4567890 <~~ Valid
    '    ABC-&456789 <~~ Invalid
    '    456-3456789 <~~ Valid

    amount = Application.InputBox("Enter case number:", "")

    '~~> Check if user pressed cancel
    If amount = False Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Check if then Case ID is valid
    If IsValidCaseNo(amount) Then
        MsgBox amount
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid case ID"
    End If
End Sub

Function IsValidCaseNo(sAmount) As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    s = sAmount

    '
    '~~> Initial basic checks
    '
    '~~> Check if the length is 11 characters
    If Len(Trim(s)) <> 11 Then GoTo Whoa
    '~~> Check if the string contains "-"
    If InStr(1, s, "-") = 0 Then GoTo Whoa
    '~~> Check if the 4th character is a "-"
    If Mid(s, 4, 1) <> "-" Then GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Loop through 1st 3 characters and check
    '~~> If they are numbers
    For i = 1 To 3
        Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
        Case 48 To 57
        Case Else: GoTo Whoa
        End Select
    Next

    '~~> Loop through last 6 characters and check
    '~~> If they are numbers
    For i = 5 To 11
        Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
        Case 48 To 57
        Case Else: GoTo Whoa
        End Select
        IsValidCaseNo = True
    Next
Whoa:
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Dim amount as String, you can test it as a string:

```
Sub GetDash()
    Dim amount As String
    amount = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter case number", Type:=2)
    If amount = "False" Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled"
    End If
End Sub
```